# it's possible to building module in Asp .net core for ERP Project like module in odoo?

Tags: asp.net-core, odoo

I want to develop ERP System in **Asp .net core** , i want to build **modules**(invoices, sms, Payment..) similar in **Odoo**, it's possible?

Comment: In short `YES`.

Comment: Yes, you can search for example projects that work with plugins/modules or frameworks that support it like: [nopCommerce](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/tree/develop/src) or [OrchardCore](https://orchardcore.net/)